# R Data table inside functions

Tags: r, data.table

I am using R data.table on my functions but I am getting a strange behaviour. On `line log <- dados[, .N, by=erros]`  data table do not sumarize data. It give me Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols). The data table has the column erros and if a run the code on command line it works perfectly. Could someone give me some help? The project can be found [here](https://github.com/ipea/validaRA).

```
estatisticas_amostra <- function(df, columnName,  type = "cpf"){
  require(data.table)
  library(data.table)
  setDT(df)
  dados_validados <- valida_doc(df[, columnName, with, F], type = type, log = TRUE)
  setDT(dados_validados)
  return(sumarizando_dados(dados_validados))

}
sumarizando_dados <- function(dados){
  log <- dados[, .N, by=erros]
  print(log)
  t <- data.table("Corretos"=0,"Primeiro digito errado"=1,"Segundo Digito errado"=2)
  log[, erros:=names(t)[match(erros, t)]]
  return(log)
}

diagnostica_RA <- function(df, nomes_colunas, types){
  if(length(types) != length(nomes_colunas)){
    stop("Types e nomes_colunas devem ter o mesmo tamanho")
  }
  estatistica <- data.frame(tipo = character(0),
                            validos = integer(0),
                            invalidos = integer(0),
                            sem_character = integer(0),
                            characters_invalido = integer(0),
                            zeros = integer(0),
                            characters_iguais = integer(0),
                            primeiro_digito_invalido = integer(0),
                            segundo_digito_invalido = integer(0)
                            )

  todas <- mapply(function(column, type){
    result <- estatisticas_amostra(df, column, type)
    result[, type:= type]
    retun(result)
  }, nomes_colunas, types)
  todas <- rbindlist(todas)
  return(todas)
}



tabulacaoDOC <- function(input_file = NULL,data = NULL, columns, types){
      require("data.table")
      if(length(columns) != length(types)){
        stop("Columns and types have to be of the same size.")
      }

      if(is.null(input_file) & is.null(data)){
        stop("You have to give a input_file or a data")
      }
      if(!is.null(input_file) & is.null(data)){
        if(file.exists(input_file)){
          data <- data.table::fread(input_file)
        }else{
          stop("It is not possible to read the input_file")
        }
      }
      diagnostica_RA(data, nomes_colunas = columns, types = types)
    }
```

Comment: Just at a first glance: Do any of the packages you are loading have the same name of a function you are trying to use? It is best practice to never use `library` or `require` in a package. Instead, you can use `package::function()` or use `@import` or `@importFrom` in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think so. Most of my functions are in brazilian portuguese and the data table functions are in English.

Comment: Just a guess, I'd try `copydados <- copy(dados)` then `log  <- copydados[, .N, by=erros]` .(Personally I wouldn't use `log` as a name either, given there is a function of that name.)

Comment: Thank you gus, i can solve it. it was the missing @import for data.table.